# No package identifier when getting value for resource

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, logcat, android-package-managers

I am trying to get list of all apps on device ThirdParty and System, I run this operation in `AsyncTask`, When the app open the task run and i see a long operation when getting this list during this operation i see that warnings printed in the `Logcat` and i think it's the reason behind the long operation:

```
11-26 09:51:23.720 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-26 09:51:23.720 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.google.android.onetimeinitializer: Resource ID #0x0
11-26 09:51:23.870 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-26 09:51:23.870 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.qualcomm.shutdownlistner: Resource ID #0x0
11-26 09:51:23.994 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-26 09:51:23.994 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.android.wallpapercropper: Resource ID #0x0
11-26 09:51:24.744 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-26 09:51:24.744 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.android.documentsui: Resource ID #0x0
11-26 09:51:24.873 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
11-26 09:51:24.874 1739-1846/com.example.AppList W/PackageManager: Failure retrieving resources for com.android.externalstorage: Resource ID #0x0
                                      ....
                                      ....
/** 
 * I got all installed and system apps on the device
 * listed as the above in the logcat as Warning.
 */
                                      ....
                                      .... to the end.
```

This is the `doInBackground` code:

```
@Override
    protected final List<App> doInBackground(List<App>... params) {

        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        List<PackageInfo> packList = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
        List<App> userApps = new ArrayList<>();
        int totalApp = appsList.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalApp; i++) {
            ApplicationInfo info = appsList.get(i);
            final App app = new App();

            app.setIcon(info.loadIcon(getActivity().getPackageManager()));
            app.setName(info.loadLabel(getActivity().getPackageManager()).toString());
            app.setPackageName(info.packageName);

            if ((info.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                userApps.add(app);
            }
        }
        return userApps;
    }
```

So how to fix this, or just How to fix the long operation?

---

**EDIT**

I tried to remove app icon functionality from the list and it's load faster than when the image is attached, so the problem in the image

@David Corsalini told me this in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/55639555?noredirect=1):

> Load the bitmap in a background thread, call this background thread from the `holder.bind()` method. I don't have the code for this one.

I am using a `ListView` with `ViewHolder` but don't know about `holder.bind()`, so How to achieve this please?!

Comment: Can you post your code, where you are trying?

Comment: Actually that is not our problem, that is the problem from android, sometimes we are getting that resources and sometimes not. And about long operation, it depends on Number of apps installed in your device.

Comment: I tested other apps and it's not have this problem, So why it's in my app, Surely  there's an error but i can't find it!

Comment: It happens only for specific applications, not for all applications.

Comment: So what to do now?!, How to fix that?, it's slow down my application

Comment: How much time It takes to load apps, its only taking 105 MS in my device for 70 applications.

Comment: 11 to 14 seconds, other apps from PlayStore make it in 5 seconds.

Comment: I didn't found any other ways to avoid data.

Comment: If you will find any solution then let me know.

Comment: I think the long load time is due to the fact that you load the icon bitmap. If you use this app list in a ListView/RecyclerView you could load the bitmap from the ViewHolder. This way you will only load the needed bitmap and only when you actually need them.

Comment: I've seen these kind of errors when trying to load System Apps icons. These apps don't have an icon, so you get the error.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini I converted the `Drawable` to `Bitmap` but i got the same result, long operation and same warnings. I get it using this line `holder.rowIcon.setImageBitmap(app.getIcon());` and `getIcon()` returns `Bitmap`.

Comment: @DavidCorsalini, You are right, i disabled the image functionality and the list loaded faster, Now as i said before i converted the drawable to bitmap but i got the same problem, So what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Load the bitmap in a background thread, call this background thread from the holder.bind() method. I don't have the code for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading app icons is taking a long time, because you are storing all the app icons as drawables in a big list - this is not a good idea, unless you have to do it. Instead, I would suggest remove that "icon" variable in your App class and load the icon in your list adapter. In getView method of your list adapter, you can set the icon drawables as below:

```
    Drawable icon;
    try {
        icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error", ex);
        icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_default);
    }

    holder.imageview.setImageDrawable(icon);
```

I don't know how you implemented your adapter, but my suggestion is to provide list of the App objects that you collected in your background task and provide the package names from those App objects. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but why the list scroll with lag?

Comment: Probably due to large amount of icons you display. You can implement a "lazy list" if you want, it makes your list smooth and consumes less memory. There are many tutorials on that topic.

Comment: Okay, I will try that.

Comment: Loading the icons in your list adapter is a terrible idea. just cache them at app start. if you optimize it a little bit it will be only a sec or two to load all of the app ICONS.

whats slow is getting localized names!